# Custom metrics for EMR Spark application that runs a schedule using AWS Data Pipelines

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, emr, metrics, amazon-cloudwatch

For our project, we have a spark application running on an EMR cluster - which runs on schedule using AWS Data Pipelines. (i.e the instances are shut down after the application/job finishes). I am currently looking at alternatives to produce custom metrics (i.e. to publish business metrics)

The best solution I found so far is to use AWS Cloudwatch API's to publish these metrics.

Are there any other alternatives to achieve the same?

Thanks